# Обратиться к контексту класса из объекта

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback, context

Я хочу создать обработчик на событие для компонента Chart из [react-google-charts](https://github.com/RakanNimer/react-google-charts)

В документации приведен пример:

```
<Chart
chartType="ScatterChart"
rows={this.state.rows}
columns={this.state.columns}
options={this.state.options}
graph_id="ScatterChart"
width="100%"
height="400px"
chartEvents={this.chartEvents} // <- Это обработчик события
/>
```

Сам chartEvents выглядит следующим образом:

```
this.chartEvents=[
{
    eventName : 'select',
    callback  : function(Chart) {
        console.log("Selected ",Chart.chart.getSelection());
    }
}];
```

Я хочу внутри обработчика вызвать функцию изменения локального состояния this.setState. Но внутри функции callback контекст ссылается на объект, который её вызывает. Как быть в такой ситуации?

```
this.chartEvents=[
{
    eventName : 'select',
    callback  : function(Chart) {
        //тут хочу обратиться к this.setState()
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте стрелочную `arrow` функцию, которая сохраняет контекст

```
this.chartEvents=[
{
    eventName : 'select',
    callback  : Chart => {
       console.log(this.setState);
    }
}];
```